# Eclipse won't start, log error says: ObjectNotFoundException: Tree element

Tags: eclipse

Last night my machine restarted while Eclipse Galileo was open.  No big deal, right?

This morning, I started my machine and tried to open Eclipse.  Instead of opening, I see this:
[image]

The error log suggests that there is some kind of problem caused by exiting with unsaved changes.

How can I get Eclipse to open and ignore those unsaved changes?  I can't even open a text file that is not part of this project with Eclipse?  There must be a way to reset this state.

**EDIT:**

I have tracked down the problem to a single file.  When I delete this file below, Eclipse opens but my projects are missing.

```
.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources\.snap
```

I do use the subversion plugin, but I don't think that is the problem.  Here is what the error log says ( abbreviated ):

```
!SESSION 2010-08-17 10:13:01.718 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=M20100211-1343
java.version=1.4.2_06
java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=en_CA
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.resources 2 10035 2010-08-17 10:13:02.656
!MESSAGE The workspace exited with unsaved changes in the previous session; refreshing workspace to recover changes.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2010-08-17 10:13:02.671
!MESSAGE An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.eclipse.core.resources (33).
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in org.eclipse.core.resources.ResourcesPlugin.start() of bundle org.eclipse.core.resources.
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:806)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:755)
...

Caused by: org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.ObjectNotFoundException: Tree element '/reports/src/com/lang/reports/OnlineReport.java' not found.
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.AbstractDataTree.handleNotFound(AbstractDataTree.java:257)
...

Root exception:
org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.ObjectNotFoundException: Tree element '/reports/src/com/lang/reports/OnlineReport.java' not found.
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.AbstractDataTree.handleNotFound(AbstractDataTree.java:257)
...

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2010-08-17 10:13:02.703
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/core/resources/IContainer
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:194)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2010-08-17 10:13:02.765
!MESSAGE The following is a complete list of bundles which are not resolved, see the prior log entry for the root cause if it exists:
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2010-08-17 10:13:02.765
!MESSAGE Bundle org.eclipse.jdt.apt.core_3.3.202.R35x_v20091130-2300 [103] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2010-08-17 10:13:02.765
!MESSAGE Bundle org.eclipse.jdt.apt.pluggable.core_1.0.201.R35x_v20090925-1100 [104] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jdt.apt.pluggable.core 2 0 2010-08-17 10:13:02.765
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.jdt.apt.core_0.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jdt.apt.pluggable.core 2 0 2010-08-17 10:13:02.765
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.tool_0.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jdt.apt.pluggable.core 2 0 2010-08-17 10:13:02.765
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.apt.dispatch_0.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jdt.apt.pluggable.core 2 0 2010-08-17 10:13:02.765
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.apt.model_0.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jdt.apt.pluggable.core 2 0 2010-08-17 10:13:02.765
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.apt.util_0.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2010-08-17 10:13:02.765
!MESSAGE Bundle org.eclipse.jdt.apt.ui_3.3.200.v20090930-2100_R35x [105] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jdt.apt.ui 2 0 2010-08-17 10:13:02.765
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.jdt.apt.core_[3.2.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2010-08-17 10:13:02.765
!MESSAGE Bundle org.eclipse.jdt.compiler.apt_1.0.201.R35x_v20090925-1100 [106] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jdt.compiler.apt 2 0 2010-08-17 10:13:02.765
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.tool_0.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2010-08-17 10:13:02.765
!MESSAGE Bundle org.eclipse.jdt.compiler.tool_1.0.100.v_981_R35x [107] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2010-08-17 10:13:02.765
!MESSAGE Bundle org.eclipse.jdt.junit4.runtime_1.1.0.v20090513-2000 [116] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jdt.junit4.runtime 2 0 2010-08-17 10:13:02.765
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.junit4_[4.4.0,5.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2010-08-17 10:13:02.765
!MESSAGE Bundle org.hamcrest.core_1.1.0.v20090501071000 [184] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2010-08-17 10:13:02.765
!MESSAGE Bundle org.junit4_4.5.0.v20090824 [186] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.junit4 2 0 2010-08-17 10:13:02.765
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.hamcrest.core_1.1.0.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2010-08-17 10:13:02.765
!MESSAGE Bundle com.collabnet.subversion.merge_2.1.0 [208] was not resolved.
```

Comment: `java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.` I think this may be the root cause! :)

Comment: try starting eclipse with another workspace and see if this works.

Comment: No can do.  Can't open another workspace.  Can't open a text file not associated with any project.  I'm stuck in limbo.

Comment: What exactly is your version(including build-no)?

Comment: eclipse.buildId = M20100211-1343
Release 3.5.2

Comment: Anyone know where the project state is kept? I don't see anything in the .metadata folder

Comment: Project state is kept in the .metadata dir!.

Comment: @pavanlimo Today it's `java.vendor=Oracle Corporation` and things didn't change

Answer (score 96, accepted):

**Recommended:** Delete `<workspace-directory>\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources\.snap`. This will not reset your workspace and your other projects won't get deleted (as answered by krishna).

**Not Recommended:** Alternatively, delete the the whole `<workspace-directory>\.metadata` directory from your workspace and restart.**This will reset your workspace and delete all your existing projects in it**.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me.  I was at least able to restart eclipse after I deleted the .snap file in .metadata.  Unfortunately I lost all my projects.  In the end I had to re-checkout all my projects from subversion.  But at least I am up and working again.

Comment: Got exactly the same here, damn.

Comment: Just happened to me - right in the middle of integration testing. Lost the server setup etc etc etc

Comment: I think the correct answer should be the one below. Above resets your whole workspace, below in the other hand keeps everything you did as it is.

Comment: worked great. I couldn't open an existing workspace. I deleted my .metadata directory, then just re-imported the existing projects into the workspace.

Comment: Why was this the accepted answer. Completely borked my install, and I have spent the next few hours fixing it.

Comment: Could you please update the answer to explain that it removes all your project setups? If you are in a hurry and not so experienced with Eclipse you get very frustrated when all your configuration is gone.
Still your solution solves the problem, but with an undesired effect.
So you still get an upvote.

Comment: thanks... i was stuck in appcelerator not working with the same error

Comment: Edited my answer to include krishna's answer, so that other people don't reset their workspace. If OP is reading this, please mark krishna's answer as accepted instead of this.

Comment: Thanks, the recommended solutions helps. My eclipse Mars.2 Release (4.5.2) didn't start beforehand.

Answer (score 146):

For this issue I had to delete the `.snap` file located in the directory :

```
<workspace-directory>\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources
```

After deleting that file, I was able to start my Eclipse with no problem.

Comment: Worked without losing projects or tasks :) Eclipse Juno (2013). Thanks!

Comment: Deleting the .snap or all .snap files recursively didn't fix it for me.

Comment: This worked pretty nice on Version: Indigo Service Release 1 Build id: 20110916-0149 on OSX. Thanks go to Krishna and bluish.

Comment: Awesome tip, man! This did it, without affecting the workspace. I had tons of config, so can't afford to reset the workspace. Thanks!

Comment: i was lost, now i am home :D thanx

Comment: @Krishna: thanks this solution for me but I just dont understand why did it occur in the first place! can u please explain?

Comment: Worked for me without loosing my Workspace. The only thing to do was Refreshing my projects to sync the Workspace with filessystem.
My env: RHEL 7, Oracle JVM 7, JBDS 7.1

Comment: Removing the `.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.jdt.core` directory resolves too

Comment: Deleting the .snap file from .metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources worked for me. Eclipse Luna then loaded ok and still had all its projects. Didn't have to make any other changes.

Comment: This also worked with Eclipse Neon, though .snap was in /.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.root

Comment: For me, on neon on RH, I had file org.eclipse.core.resources/14.snap. What is that all about? Worked anyway, thanks.

Comment: This removed my projects and basically made me have to start from scratch, so a downvote from me.

Answer (score 15):

Ran into this error.

There was no .snap file in my .metadata folder.

I had to delete this:

```
<workspace>/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.root/d+.tree
```

d+=> some number.

Then I had to re-import the projects and re-assign the working sets. I preferred it over opening a new workspace and redoing settings.

Comment: This worked for me. Was a pain to re-create my projects but the other answers didn't help me.

Comment: this worked for me.  I re-imported my projects so I didn't have to re-create them.  Everything is as before

Comment: Did not work for me. Had to delete .metadata folder.

Comment: In my case (Jaspersoft Studio 5.5.1 final) it made all projects disappear from the Project Explorer, except the default one (and I don't know how to open them).

Answer (score 5):

Deleting .snap file worked perfect for me.

1. Delete .snap file from the directory - workspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources.
2. Import the workspace (existing projects into workspace - do not copy folders into workspace again).

Answer (score 2):

For anyone interested, I had the exact same problem and deleting the file .metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.snap did the trick for me.

Answer (score 1):

Had similar problem.

Log file said exception was caused by corruption in the project tree -- a very vague description.

Deleting individual files and directories in /.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources didn't work for me. I had to delete the entire /.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources directory. I lost the entire project tree but not the projects. They were still in the workspace and just needed to be imported back into Eclipse. I also did not lose the large numbers of plugins configured for working Java, Android, PHP, C++, J2EE, etc.

This is the second time I encountered a project tree related corruption. The first time I deleted the .metadata altogether and then spent a very long time putting back all the plugins and projects. The direction the other answers here were useful in zeroing in on just the org.eclipse.core.resources directory. Seems deleting the whole directory just results in only needing to reimport all the projects.

Your mileage may vary...

Comment: I had to do this too, just deleting .snap didn't fix it. I'm using Luna SR1 (4.4.1).

Answer (score 1):

This also works when you receive this error from Information Design Tool (IDT) (Business Objects BI4).

1. Delete .snap file from this directory.
   Please note that you Will lose all your local projects.  Hopefully your modifications have been recently saved to a repository.

Directory - 
C:\Users\xxxxuser.name.businessobjects\bimodeler_14\workspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources\

Comment: Deleting (or renaming) the .snap file helped in deed (without losing the whole workspace!!!). Thanks!

Comment: I found the file here: `C:\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources\.snap` - which is the same path, except the path shown above is missing some backslashes and the workspace is in a different location ...

Answer (score 1):

**Use the clean option**

I had this error. I start eclipse with "clean" option and that worked for me.

```
eclipse.exe -clean
```

Eclipse starts and all projects ok.

Comment: Tried this with eclipse neon. Didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

solution: delete .metadata folder in your last workspace. 
reason: Maybe you force shutdown/restart your computer, while your eclipse still running.

Answer (score 0):

**Just a little tip that might help people avoid an issue that I encountered.**

In my case there were multiple workspace directories on my machine.  When I ran the mvn sonar:sonar goal then it created its own workspace directory, placed the snapshot (.snap files) in there, and changed a setting to tell maven to look there for changes first.  However, this was not my workspace that I was using, so the snapshot was never being updated with my changes.  So when maven used that snapshot it could not find the files in their old locations.  So I had to eliminate that workspace to resolve the issue.  This worked because maven then looked in the next workspace on its list, my workspace, for the snapshot instead of the one added (but never updated) by the sonar goal.

So you might need to search your entire hard drive for *.snap files to see if there is more one workspace being used on your machine.

Answer (score 0):

Check your environment variables _JAVA_OPTION path. I had HP UFT installed on my system and I set _JAVA_OPTION to  IGNOREME_JAVA_OPTION for both system and environment variable. After reboot, eclipse showed the same error " check log file". Removed the IGNOREME and eclipse no issues. This could be another possibility that could be looked at to fix the eclipse.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem, this happens when you force shutdown/restart your computer, while your eclipse still running.
Deleting .metadata folder worked for me. Delete all the metadata and then import your project from that same workspace.

Answer (score 0):

Rather deleting whole .metadata folder, which in turns delete your projects from workspace, try to find the .snap files and delete them.
.snap files are the snapshot of workspace's temporary instance which will be saved on clean & close of workspace.

Answer (score 0):

Delete all the *.Snap files in the path workspace-directory>.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources