# how to get workspace path in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, workspace, pde

I am doing to study about PDE(Eclipse Plugin Project).

I need to get workspace path.

My text widget(swt) should to be set current workspace path.

How to get workspace path in eclipse?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to tell Eclipse Workspace?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4332943/how-to-tell-eclipse-workspace)

Comment: Here is an answer I found http://ispecsoft.com/Taught1/post/2016/05/26/How-to-find-Eclipse-Project-workspace-location.aspx

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You want:

```
ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot().getLocation().toString();
```

Comment: You need to add org.eclipse.core.resources to the list of dependencies to use ResourcesPlugin.

Answer (score 9):

File -> Switch Workspace -> Other 
the shown directory is your current workspace

Comment: Sorry, I want to get code of String value.

Comment: @user3639147 - No need to downvote. - This answer could be useful to someone other than you.

Comment: It's actually exactly what I needed, thanks