# Get the workspace root

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am developing an eclipse plugin and I am trying to get the workspace root in order to acces later a file from the workspace and read something from it.

**I skipped the error handling for a shorter code**

```
IProject project = file.getProject(); // file is the file open in editor
IFolder specificFolder = project.getFolder("test");
IFile fileFromSpecFolder = specificFolder.getFile("test.txt");
Path path = Paths.get(fileFromSpecFolder.getLocationURI());
BufferedReader reader = createReaderFor(path);
// later on read something from the file...
```

The problem is that the implemnted `getProject` method `returns itself for projects or null for the project root`.

```
public IProject getProject() {
    return workspace.getRoot().getProject(path.segment(0));
}
```

`path.segment(0))` contains the workspace root

Am I over complicating things here? How could I achieve this in another way?

Comment: Search first? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23691464/how-to-get-workspace-path-in-eclipse

Comment: @VeselinDavidov I saw that question but didn't knew if it is exactly my case

Comment: Sorry but I really don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: @greg-449 I want to get the path of a file from the workspace. The file is located in a fixed location: `%workspaceroot%/test/test.txt`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get the `IFile` for a path in the workspace using:

```
IWorkspaceRoot root = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot();

IPath path = new Path("project/folder/file");

IFile file = root.getFileForLocation(path);
```

To read the contents of a file in the workspace you should use `IFile.getContents`:

```
InputStream is = file.getContents();
```

Use `IFile.getCharset` to get the character set of a text file:

```
String charset = file.getCharset();
```

So a `Reader` for the file would be:

```
Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(is, charset);
```

Note that `Path` is `org.eclipse.core.runtime.Path`

Comment: Should I use `Path path` instead of `IPath path`? The type Path cannot be instantiated.

Comment: You have the wrong `Path` class import - this is `org.eclipse.core.runtime.Path` **not** `java.nio.file.Path`