# How to prompt workspace dialog in eclipse rcp product

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have added osgi.instance.area.default entry product_name.product file with @user.home/product_name_workspace and built the product,hoping users will get the workspace dialog during product launch from exe. but the same is not working.
Followed below stackoverflow entry but of no help.

[How to tell Eclipse Workspace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4332943/how-to-tell-eclipse-workspace)

So far tried below:

1. updated config.ini file osgi.instance.area.default=@user.home/product_name_workspace and with absolute paths like C:\temp\workspace
2. Theconfiguration.settings\org.eclipse.ui.ide.prefs file SHOW_WORKSPACE_SELECTION_DIALOG=true
3. added product_name.ini file with -showlocation and -showworkspace

   all above are failing.

I could see a bugzilla entry [https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=134412)id=134412 it holds true for me now. Any help would be appreciated. I am using Luna + windows7 64bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set a default location then Eclipse will always use that if no location is specified and it will not prompt the user.

The `SHOW_WORKSPACE_SELECTION_DIALOG` preference is only used to stop the workspace location prompt dialog from showing. It cannot be used to force it to show.

`-showlocation` just controls showing the workspace location in the window title. It is not related to the prompt dialog.

The only way to change this behavior would be to write your own `IApplication` to change this behavior. This is very difficult if you are using all the normal Eclipse IDE functionality.

Comment: Thanks greg-449 that helped. sorry for late reply on this.As you have suggested I have used ChooseWorkspaceDialog object in IApplication.start() to prompt the workspace dialog. I have used ChooseWorkspaceData to set the content in ChooseWorkspaceDialog object. for e.g. the user.home directory path and message title etc.