# Eclipse is not opening in my windows xp m/c

Tags: java, eclipse

I am having issues with opening my eclipse(helios) in my windows xp m/c.
I tried to open Eclipse,After specifying the workspace i see the below error message:

[image: Error Window]

I am using java 7 and eclipse helios.

1. Initially i  reinstalled java7 and it worked. Today when i try to open the eclipse i face the same issue.
2. I also tried deleting the entire **.metadata.plugins** folder but still facing the same issue.
3. I also tried giving different workspace but still it shows the same error.

Below is the log file that was mentioned in the error window.

```
 !SESSION 2013-10-28 20:26:34.140 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=M20110210-1200
java.version=1.7.0_40
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2013-10-28 20:26:43.546
!MESSAGE An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.eclipse.core.resources (66).
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in org.eclipse.core.resources.ResourcesPlugin.start() of bundle org.eclipse.core.resources.
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:806)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:755)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:370)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:284)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:417)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.setLazyTrigger(BundleLoader.java:265)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:106)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:453)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:216)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:393)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.SingleSourcePackage.loadClass(SingleSourcePackage.java:33)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:466)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:422)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:410)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:369)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:620)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:575)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1408)
Caused by: java.lang.InternalError
    at java.util.Currency$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.util.Currency.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at java.text.DecimalFormatSymbols.initialize(Unknown Source)
    at java.text.DecimalFormatSymbols.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.text.DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.text.NumberFormat.getInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.text.NumberFormat.getIntegerInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.initialize(Unknown Source)
    at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.debug.EclipseDebugTrace.<clinit>(EclipseDebugTrace.java:51)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.debug.FrameworkDebugOptions.setFile(FrameworkDebugOptions.java:438)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.DataArea.createLocation(DataArea.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.DataArea.initializeLocation(DataArea.java:147)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.DataArea.assertLocationInitialized(DataArea.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.DataArea.getStateLocation(DataArea.java:120)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.InternalPlatform.getStateLocation(InternalPlatform.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.Plugin.getStateLocation(Plugin.java:312)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.LocalMetaArea.<init>(LocalMetaArea.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.core.resources.ResourcesPlugin.start(ResourcesPlugin.java:398)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:783)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:774)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\currency.data (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    ... 52 more
Root exception:
java.lang.InternalError
    at java.util.Currency$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.util.Currency.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at java.text.DecimalFormatSymbols.initialize(Unknown Source)
    at java.text.DecimalFormatSymbols.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.text.DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.text.NumberFormat.getInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.text.NumberFormat.getIntegerInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.initialize(Unknown Source)
    at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.debug.EclipseDebugTrace.<clinit>(EclipseDebugTrace.java:51)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.debug.FrameworkDebugOptions.setFile(FrameworkDebugOptions.java:438)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.DataArea.createLocation(DataArea.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.DataArea.initializeLocation(DataArea.java:147)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.DataArea.assertLocationInitialized(DataArea.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.DataArea.getStateLocation(DataArea.java:120)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.InternalPlatform.getStateLocation(InternalPlatform.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.Plugin.getStateLocation(Plugin.java:312)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.LocalMetaArea.<init>(LocalMetaArea.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.core.resources.ResourcesPlugin.start(ResourcesPlugin.java:398)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:783)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:774)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:755)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:370)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:284)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:417)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.setLazyTrigger(BundleLoader.java:265)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:106)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:453)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:216)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:393)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.SingleSourcePackage.loadClass(SingleSourcePackage.java:33)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:466)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:422)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:410)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:369)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:620)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:575)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1408)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\currency.data (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    ... 52 more

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2013-10-28 20:26:43.593
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/core/resources/IContainer
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:369)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:620)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:575)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1408)
Caused by: org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter$TerminatingClassNotFoundException: An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.eclipse.core.resources (66).
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:121)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:453)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:216)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:393)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.SingleSourcePackage.loadClass(SingleSourcePackage.java:33)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:466)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:422)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:410)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in org.eclipse.core.resources.ResourcesPlugin.start() of bundle org.eclipse.core.resources.
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:806)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:755)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:370)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:284)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:417)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.setLazyTrigger(BundleLoader.java:265)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:106)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.InternalError
    at java.util.Currency$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.util.Currency.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at java.text.DecimalFormatSymbols.initialize(Unknown Source)
    at java.text.DecimalFormatSymbols.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.text.DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.text.NumberFormat.getInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.text.NumberFormat.getIntegerInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.initialize(Unknown Source)
    at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.debug.EclipseDebugTrace.<clinit>(EclipseDebugTrace.java:51)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.debug.FrameworkDebugOptions.setFile(FrameworkDebugOptions.java:438)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.DataArea.createLocation(DataArea.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.DataArea.initializeLocation(DataArea.java:147)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.DataArea.assertLocationInitialized(DataArea.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.DataArea.getStateLocation(DataArea.java:120)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.InternalPlatform.getStateLocation(InternalPlatform.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.Plugin.getStateLocation(Plugin.java:312)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.LocalMetaArea.<init>(LocalMetaArea.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.core.resources.ResourcesPlugin.start(ResourcesPlugin.java:398)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:783)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:774)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\currency.data (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    ... 52 more

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui.ide 4 0 2013-10-28 20:26:43.734
!MESSAGE 
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.IDEWorkbenchPlugin.stop() of bundle org.eclipse.ui.ide.
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.stop(BundleContextImpl.java:863)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.stopWorker(BundleHost.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.suspend(AbstractBundle.java:550)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.suspendBundle(Framework.java:1097)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.decFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:597)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.shutdown(StartLevelManager.java:215)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.InternalSystemBundle.suspend(InternalSystemBundle.java:266)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.shutdown(Framework.java:690)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.close(Framework.java:588)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.shutdown(EclipseStarter.java:415)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:198)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:620)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:575)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1408)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.eclipse.osgi.framework.debug.EclipseDebugTrace
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.debug.FrameworkDebugOptions.setFile(FrameworkDebugOptions.java:438)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.DataArea.createLocation(DataArea.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.DataArea.initializeLocation(DataArea.java:147)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.DataArea.assertLocationInitialized(DataArea.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.DataArea.getStateLocation(DataArea.java:125)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.InstancePreferences.getBaseLocation(InstancePreferences.java:44)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.InstancePreferences.initializeChildren(InstancePreferences.java:199)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.InstancePreferences.<init>(InstancePreferences.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.InstancePreferences.internalCreate(InstancePreferences.java:209)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.EclipsePreferences.create(EclipsePreferences.java:289)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.EclipsePreferences.create(EclipsePreferences.java:277)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.PreferencesService.createNode(PreferencesService.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.RootPreferences.getChild(RootPreferences.java:63)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.RootPreferences.getNode(RootPreferences.java:96)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.RootPreferences.node(RootPreferences.java:85)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.legacy.PreferenceForwarder.<init>(PreferenceForwarder.java:37)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.Plugin$1.run(Plugin.java:369)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.Plugin.getPluginPreferences(Plugin.java:372)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.Plugin.savePluginPreferences(Plugin.java:393)
    at org.eclipse.ui.plugin.AbstractUIPlugin.savePreferenceStore(AbstractUIPlugin.java:526)
    at org.eclipse.ui.plugin.AbstractUIPlugin.stop(AbstractUIPlugin.java:630)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.IDEWorkbenchPlugin.stop(IDEWorkbenchPlugin.java:329)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$2.run(BundleContextImpl.java:843)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.stop(BundleContextImpl.java:836)
    ... 18 more
Root exception:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.eclipse.osgi.framework.debug.EclipseDebugTrace
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.debug.FrameworkDebugOptions.setFile(FrameworkDebugOptions.java:438)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.DataArea.createLocation(DataArea.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.DataArea.initializeLocation(DataArea.java:147)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.DataArea.assertLocationInitialized(DataArea.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.DataArea.getStateLocation(DataArea.java:125)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.InstancePreferences.getBaseLocation(InstancePreferences.java:44)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.InstancePreferences.initializeChildren(InstancePreferences.java:199)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.InstancePreferences.<init>(InstancePreferences.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.InstancePreferences.internalCreate(InstancePreferences.java:209)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.EclipsePreferences.create(EclipsePreferences.java:289)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.EclipsePreferences.create(EclipsePreferences.java:277)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.PreferencesService.createNode(PreferencesService.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.RootPreferences.getChild(RootPreferences.java:63)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.RootPreferences.getNode(RootPreferences.java:96)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.RootPreferences.node(RootPreferences.java:85)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.legacy.PreferenceForwarder.<init>(PreferenceForwarder.java:37)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.Plugin$1.run(Plugin.java:369)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.Plugin.getPluginPreferences(Plugin.java:372)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.Plugin.savePluginPreferences(Plugin.java:393)
    at org.eclipse.ui.plugin.AbstractUIPlugin.savePreferenceStore(AbstractUIPlugin.java:526)
    at org.eclipse.ui.plugin.AbstractUIPlugin.stop(AbstractUIPlugin.java:630)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.IDEWorkbenchPlugin.stop(IDEWorkbenchPlugin.java:329)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$2.run(BundleContextImpl.java:843)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.stop(BundleContextImpl.java:836)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.stopWorker(BundleHost.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.suspend(AbstractBundle.java:550)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.suspendBundle(Framework.java:1097)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.decFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:597)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.shutdown(StartLevelManager.java:215)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.InternalSystemBundle.suspend(InternalSystemBundle.java:266)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.shutdown(Framework.java:690)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.close(Framework.java:588)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.shutdown(EclipseStarter.java:415)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:198)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:620)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:575)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1408)
```

Comment: Try running Eclipse from the command line with the `-clean` option (so, `eclipse -clean`).

Comment: still gives the same error.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Eclipse won't start, log error says: ObjectNotFoundException: Tree element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505187/eclipse-wont-start-log-error-says-objectnotfoundexception-tree-element)

Answer (score -1):

When I used to use Eclipse (using IntelliJ now) I used to run in to this problem a lot. I think the simplest solution would probably be to re-install Eclipse and then re-import all of your projects again.

Alternatively, you could just un-install Eclipse and download a different IDE such as [IntelliJ](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) or [NetBeans](https://netbeans.org/) (I'd probably recommend IntelliJ based on experience).